# Like Button not showing up on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, iweb

Like Button not showing up after creating html on the facebook site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.  Shows up as blank box.  Seems very straight forward and simple, but can't get it to work.  Here is the code that is generated:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <script>
      (function(d, s, id) {   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  
        js = d.createElement(s); 
        js.id = id;  
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";  
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
      }
      (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you also copy and paste the actual Like button code? It looks something like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Your code above is simply to load the Facebook API. You need the additional code above to actually render a button. Double check the plugin page again and ensure you copy all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that your page doesn't have country or age restrictions:

http://www.moorewebexposure.com/internet/facebook-like-button-not-showing/

Answer (score 0):

The Like button is showing up in the editor, but not in the browsers.  Do I have to have access to the Facebook page I'm trying to link to, to change any setting?